# asp.net page does not displaying after publishing on production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a website in asp.net. It has a menu control.

It is working fine in development environment but not in the production environment.

I have link on menu control to the page called `connect.aspx`. When I click on this link it's redirected to

```
http://websitename.com/ErrorPage.htm?aspxerrorpath=/connect.aspx
```

where as it should be redirected to the below link

```
http://websitename.com/connect.aspx**
```

I searched on google but does not getting exact reason behind it.

Please help...

Comment: try using the absolute path. Using the tilt sign (~) in the path is causing the error.

Comment: how did you set *NavigateUrl* proerpty on menu items ? you should drop your control source/code here.

Comment: please turn the `customErrorMode` `on` and see the error. then post the detail in this question.

Comment: @Murtaza i have used (~) sign.

<asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" NavigateUrl="~/index.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Connect" Value="Connect" NavigateUrl="~/connect.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>

but when i click in index.aspx it display that page. why??

Comment: can you use your absolute path, like "/connect.aspx"

Comment: @Murtaza

I got the solution there was a small error.
In web.config file i changed debug=false. it works
 <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
previously it was debug="true"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool! Thats correct, before moving to production always remember to set it to false. Use FileSystem way and host your site on IIS while development also. It will help you to have the similar environment.